# How to get bulk id from sequence in spring boot via hibernate

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data

I have multi instance spring boot application and using spring data and want to get bulk 50 id from sequence and increment by 1 without going to db unless it reaches 50. My sequence is separate from any table and i want to make sure every instance gets unique id from sequence is it possible? Previously i try to get sequence id with native query but i think i can do it using with @Entity class but how?